# Why is it harder to walk on sand as opposed to a flat floor although the former has a higher friction coefficient?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

It is a common experience that it is harder to walk on sand as opposed to walking on a sleek flat floor, even though it is evident that the former is more abrasive than the latter?

Comment: Just to address the elephant in the room: you realize the sand is displaced by the pressure exerted by the feet and will not provide an ideal newtonian opposite force since it is put in motion?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I think that, additionally, the viscous motion of sand particles moving against each other, as one is trying to get normal-upward and reaction-forward forces from it, also makes it harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of Newton’s third law, for every action there is an equal but opposite reaction. When your feet push on the ground, the ground pushes back. The force that your foot exerts on a flat ground is mainly determined by friction. The higher the friction, the more efficiently you can walk. If the frictional force is decreased, the harder it will be to walk. And the loose sand under your feet results in a diminished frictional force as compared to a flat floor, because the sand can move easily.

Since the frictional force is now smaller, the reaction force of your feet in the sand is also smaller and  it will require more effort on your part to walk a similar distance on hard ground.

We can also say that your body will also need to expend more energy for each step since this energy will be given by $$W=F \times d$$ where $d$ is the distance travelled for each step, and $F$ is the force exerted for each step. Your body will exert a greater force for each step and your body will use more energy to travel the same overall distance.

Comment: Who is Newton ?

Comment: Sir Isaac Newton. Check the Wikipedia link for him. He made many crucial contributions to physics and math. Good luck.

Comment: I appreciate the encouragement.

Comment: No worries. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Soft sand deforms when you step on it. The force applied by your foot to the sand moves through the deformation distance, performing work on the sand which your muscles provide. That work does not assist your propulsion; it is lost to the sand.

The sleek flat floor does not deform when you walk on it and therefore does not "steal" work from you as you walk.

Answer (score 1):

Walking is applying force on an object and, that object keeping the same approximate location, being propelled in return in the opposite direction. If said object is mobile, like a box on a slippery floor, when you push it it will move and offer no resistance. This resistance is what makes walking possible. This is why sand or, worse, water, are not ideal to walk on (except if you are tiny and your size encounters other effects like surface tension or being too light to displace the grains of sand). Note that if you weighted 100 times more, your flat floor will crush under you and be suboptimal for walking too.